# How to have a for loop only print a string when the condition is met in Python

Tags: python-3.x, list, for-loop, if-statement

I am trying to check if my user input exist in a list and ONLY print out when the condition of the specific user input is met. But my current code does not perform this way, instead it prints out my else statements along with it.

Below is an example list of what I'm working with:

```
some_ls = [('abc', '123be33da28891e6335962b2484445fb'), ('def', '123be33da28891e6335962b2484445cb'), ('ghi', 'f2ecfad3e0f5d19c3365848449a91bbc'), ('jkl', 'aef14a39f7cbf175dfc59a4d52105847')]
```

My block of code to complete the checking:

```
for elem in some_ls:
        if user_input == elem[1]:
            print (f"{user_input}{' was FOUND!'}")
            print (f"{'Matched to : '}{elem}\n")
        else:
            print ("Further processing ...")
            # Further processing code here
```

The output:

> Please enter a value : aef14a39f7cbf175dfc59a4d52105847
> Further processing ...
> Further processing ...
> Further processing ...
> aef14a39f7cbf175dfc59a4d52105847 was FOUND!
> Matched to : ('jkl', 'aef14a39f7cbf175dfc59a4d52105847')

What I don't want appearing here is the "Further processing ..." printed out as I only want to work with inputs that are not in my current list. I have tried using break in my if else statements and it causes my output to not be accurate as if cuts off right after the first line leaving me only with "Further processing ..." even though I know the value entered is in my list.

Answer (score 0):

You can `break` when you find a match. But also, don't print "not found" until the entire list is searched.

```
for elem in some_ls:
    if user_input == elem[1]:
        print (f"{user_input}{' was FOUND!'}")
        print (f"{'Matched to : '}{elem}\n")
        break
else:
    print ("Further processing ...")
    # Further processing code here
```